# Closure with confusing usort

Tags: php, closures, usort

I am trying to rewrite a co-developers script and ran across this little gem, I for the life of me cannot even understand what it does, much less how to refactor it. Would someone explain to me what it does, and if my interpretation of his code is correct?

the original code:

```
$f = "return (${$v[0]}['{$k}'] - ${$v[1]}['{$k}']);";
usort($results, create_function('$a,$b',$f));
```

my attempt and rewriting it as a closure:

```
$f = function ($k,$v)
{
    return ($v[0][$k] - $v[1][$k]);
};

usort($results, $f($k, $v));
```

**EDIT**

For clarity, `$k` is a random string, and `$v` is an array of either `['a','b']` or an array of `['b','a']`

I'm really lost on what the attempt was, maybe it was this?

```
usort($results, function () USE ($k,$v) 
{
    return ($v[0][$k] - $v[1][$k]);
});
```

Comment: `usort($results, $f('$a,$b'));` --- what you do here: you call a function and pass a string argument to it (while it expects 2 arguments passed). Don't put it in a variable but create it in-place instead and you'll be fine.

Comment: "maybe it was this?" --- may be it was that. What is your problem though?

Comment: I am trying to change what he did into something more readable, as I don't understand what the attempt was, like if he was attempting a weighting function. Its hard to explain it if you don't understand the attempt

Comment: So, what actually you don't understand? You don't understand how `create_function` works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to do this

```
$f = function ($k,$v)
{
    return ($v[0][$k] - $v[1][$k]);
};

usort($results, $f);
```

Read more about [Closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) in php.net